# How can I regex match only lines containing exact count of tabs?

Tags: regex, sed

Using `sed` how can I match only lines containing the exact count of two tabs in order to remove their `\n`.

#### Example:

Delete `\n` in  line 1 and 3 only:

**Input:**

```
foo \t bar \t foo
foo \t bar foo
foo \t bar \t foo
foo \t bar \t foo \t bar
```

**Expected output:**

```
foo \t bar \t foofoo \t bar foo
foo \t bar \t foofoo \t bar \t foo \t bar
```

I tried this regex in Vim but it matches the 4th line as well: `/\v\t.*\t.*`

Comment: Are `\t` literal characters or the tab character?

Comment: Simple answer: you can't. It's very difficult to use sed to combine lines. If you use its "hold space" functionality it might be possible, but it would probably be easier to use something else.

Comment: However, if you just want to *match* the lines, `/^[^\t]*\t[^\t]*\t[^\t]*$/` should work

Comment: Hmmm... looks like I missed the `N` instruction. You can do this with `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use awk for this: if the line has 3 tab-separated fields, print the line without a newline

```
awk -F'\t' '{printf "%s%s", $0, (NF==3 ? "" : ORS)}' file
```

However, if the *next* line also has 3 fields, it will join with the following line. Your question is not clear about this edge case. If you just want to join, then

```
awk -F'\t' 'NF==3 {line = $0; getline; $0 = line $0} 1' file
```

These 2 commands produce the same output with your sample input.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/^[^\t]*\t[^\t]*\t[^\t]*$/N;s/\n//'
```

#### Explanation:

- `/^[^\t]*\t[^\t]*\t[^\t]*$/` matches a line with exactly 2 tab characters on it
- `N` appends a line to the input buffer
- `s/\n//` removes the newline between the two lines now in the input buffer

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -pe 'chomp if 2 == tr/\t//' < input > output
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line
- [chomp](http://p3rl.org/chomp) removes the final newline
- `tr///` is the transliteration operator similar to `tr`, it returns the number of matching characters

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;s/\t/&/3;t;s//&/2;T;N;s/\n//;ta' file
```

Match 3 or more tabs, break out. Match 1 or less tabs, break out. Match 2 tabs, append next line and remove the newline between the two lines and go to the start to check for 2 tabs.